# NullInjectorError: No provider for function DomSharedStylesHost(_doc) in IE 11 for Angular 9 app with angular material 9.1

Tags: angular, angular-material, internet-explorer-11

I am using anuglar 9 app with angular material 9.1. I am able to see the application works fine in Chrome, MS Edge, mozilla. But for IE 11, I am getting following error in the console.

[image]

one of the component is using Renderer2 to dynamically add elements to HTML page. I have no clue what is the fix for this error.

Comment: Sounds like you should check polyfils.ts for compatibility with IE

Comment: Did you try to check on which line of code you got this error? If possible then try to post any sample code. it may help us to understand the issue properly.

Comment: Bozhinovski & Deepak-MSFT, this error is in vendor.js . Based on the error it is expecting to add provider. Not sure what provider and which provider.

Comment: Only picture of the error is not giving the exact idea about the issue. Try to provide more information about the issue. Is this error also occurs with the empty new project? If possible for you then try to provide the detailed minimal steps to produce this error. We will try to follow your steps to check for the issue. It can help us to understand the issue properly.

Comment: Bozhinovski - Your comments helped me to fix this issue. I had to include polyfils for es5.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution to the issue. I suggest you post your solution as an answer for this thread and try to mark your own answer as an answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using .net with Angular + angular material as front end. We had above mentioned issue in IE11 . I was adding specific polyfills. Also the error message was redirecting for other solutions. Finally I decided to include all polyfills.  Thanks to  Bozhinovski.

Here is the code which I have added in bundleconfig.cs.

```
 bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/angular")
    .IncludeDirectory("~/dist/libs/", "*.js", true)
          .Include("~/dist/libs/runtime*",
                "~/dist/libs/polyfills*",
                "~/dist/libs/vendor*",
                "~/dist/libs/main*"));
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to this issue. I suggest you try to mark your own answer when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.